# How do I link these buttons to their layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I was wondering if you guys can help me on my app. It’s something really easy for you guys that I’m missing. I’m trying to link buttons on one layout to navigate to other layouts. These six buttons should go to their six different layouts…

Button 7 should go to the layout Number7
I already did Button 1 and it works to number1.

Here’s a screenshot of the layout and here is my code to my main.java: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aB0Y.jpg

```
package com.example.isthisyourluckyday;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
          final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

          b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Number1.class));

                 }
          });
   }
}
```

Also….. Here is number7.java which should link to the number7 layout

```
package com.example.isthisyourluckyday;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Number7 extends Activity {
                                             Button button7;
                                             @Override
                                             protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                                   setContentView(R.layout.number7);
}}
```

If you guys can please help me out I’d  really appreciate it.

Comment: it's too foggy I can't get what you need. would you calm down and explain clearly what you want?

Comment: I think you want to link to new activities with those layouts, right?

Answer (score 0):

If the first button works, where is the problem with the others ?

Below all the code :

```
public class Main extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private final Button button1;
private final Button button2;
private final Button button3;
private final Button button4;
private final Button button5;
private final Button button6;
private final Button button7;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);
    button7.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.equals(button1))
        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Number1.class));
    else if(v.equals(button2))
        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Number2.class));
    else if(v.equals(button3))
        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Number3.class));
    else if(v.equals(button4))
        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Number4.class));
    else if(v.equals(button5))
        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Number5.class));
    else if(v.equals(button6))
        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Number6.class));
    else if(v.equals(button7))
        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Number7.class));

}
}
```

The Main class can implement OnClickListener to have only one onClick() function.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this properly, but you get the idea. It is similar to the other answer, but the code is a bit cleaner and has less repetition in my opinion.

```
package com.example.isthisyourluckyday;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    final Button[] buttons = new Button[7];
    final Class[] classes = { Number1.class, Number3.class,  Number3.class,  
            Number4.class,  Number5.class,  Number6.class,  Number7.class };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        buttons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);

        for(Button b : buttons){
            b.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for(int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
            if(buttons[i].equals(v)){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, classes[i]);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start an activity like this
    startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Number1.class));
you are telling Android to start the Number1 activity. So if you want to start another activity you just   do the same thing you did:

```
final Button b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);    
b7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Number7.class));
  }
});
```

This is not elegant, but will do the trick.

You could also define a "tag" on each button like

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="1"
        android:onClick="choose"/>
```

then in your activity add a method

```
public void choose(View view) {
        String number = view.getTag().toString();
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.isthisyourluckyday", "com.example.isthisyourluckyday.Number"+number));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```